# Google Shopping API - multiple store information

Tags: api, search

We are developing an app for mobile, Mainly using Google Shopping API.
In the response we are getting one store info for one particular product.
Is there any other way to get multiple store info for one product in the response for Google Shopping API

Regards,
Bhat

Answer (score 0):

if you figure out the GTIN for a product, then search by that GTIN as the query, then each result should come back as a different store

it just means usually you have to do a search on the query, grab the top most relevant GTIN, then make another request to get the store info. Thats how I have done it anyways, would be interested to know if you solved it any other way :)

Comment: Horse.. Thenx a lot. We also followed your way. Taking GTIN of Particular Product and Sending another request. :)